# Adding an OpenGL framework in Xcode 4

Tags: c++, frameworks, xcode4, target

I'm using Xcode 4 for my C++ programming. I want to add a framework, specifically an OpenGL framework, and I'm not quite used to where things are yet. It says in the help documentation that I should select the target, and from there I get the summery pane where I can add a linked framework/library. When I do that, the summery pane doesn't show up. It does show up when my target is a cocoa application, but since I'm programming in C++, I choose the command line tool, and select the language from there. So, how exactly do I add the OpenGL framework to my target?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

---

maybe go under "build phases" (instead of "summary") and then click "Link Binary With Libraries" and add button then search OpenGL.framework
im not sure 100%, im new to this too :)

Comment: The Summary tab doesn't always show up as it's more of a "Cocoa convenience". You're correct that the Link... build phase under the Build Phases tab is the place to look as the linked libraries group of the Summary tab is effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to go to your project settings, and under `Linking -> Other Linking Flags` add:

```
-framework OpenGL
```

Answer (score 0):

In your project, create a group 'frameworks' (not really necessary but keeps things organized)

With Finder goto: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

Locate the OpenGL.framework folder
Drag and drop the folder into your XCode project (in the frameworks group)
Don't copy the files(!)

Probably you want to copy 'GLUT.framework' as well.