# Adding a framework to XCode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, build-automation

of course i did research before posting my question.

I looked at
[How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)
[Adding Framework in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334966/adding-framework-in-xcode-4)
[Adding an OpenGL framework in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395721/adding-an-opengl-framework-in-xcode-4)
[XCode 4 adding dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801709/xcode-4-adding-dylib)

but whole thing is becoming wrong.

My goal: **Add (CorePlot) framework to XCode Mac project** (not an iPhone one)

My environment: OSX Lion 10.7, SDK Lion, XCode 4.1 (4B110)

My steps:

- Opened XCode, created new project
- Downloaded CorePlot into my libraries directory (like ~/Applications/LIBS)
- Opened project preferences, via (+) opened dialog to add framework
- Add existing framework (+ copy files to dest. group if needed)
- Selected directory was ~/Applications/LIBS/CorePlot/Binaries/MacOS/CorePlot.framework/
- DnD CorePlot to Frameworks Group
- Added CorePlot to `Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries`

and ran my project

what I got is this error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Frameworks/CorePlot.framework/Versions/A/CorePlot
Referenced from: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/metralight-hjuvuwlhgohrtdeepvcymnsaxomc/Build/Products/Debug/metralight.app/Contents/MacOS/metralight
Reason: image not found
```

And in fact, when I looked into given directory (app bundle) there was no directory `Frameworks` and so the linking cannot be successful

I have searched one more, and found, that I can create `Build Rule` and copy files into final binary bundle via some script, but is this only way how to do this?

Isn't there some option to just turn on/off copying linked frameworks to final bundle?

Note that CorePlot target '.framework' has `Dynamic Library Install Name` set to `@loader_path/../Frameworks/CorePlot.framework/Versions/A/CorePlot`, so it is looking in right place in final binary bundle

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After adding framework via "Add existing framework"

- Go to `Project Settings` > `Build Phases`
- In right bottom corner click `Add buid phase` > `Copy Files`
- Select **Destination** > `Frameworks`
- Drag&Drop framework to files list

And that's it.

Comment: k i wrked it out like this no need to add the files via "add existing framework"

Comment: Tank you! Tks! Tks! +1

Answer (score 3):

Another important detail here - you must have the "Runtime search path" to be defined in the projects, it's empty by default.

Something like this:

```
LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = @loader_path/../Frameworks
```