# Crash with SBJSON library

Tags: objective-c

following code is copied from Stig Brautaset JSON library - I removed the comments to be more clear.

```
@interface NSString (NSString_SBJSON)

- (id)JSONFragmentValue;
- (id)JSONValue;

@end
```

I have a crash when I call:

```
NSString *jsonString = [request responseString];
...
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];//here is the crash with invalid selector.
```

I added this:

```
if (![jsonString respondsToSelector:@selector(JSONValue)]) 
{
   NSLog(@"fix this!!!\n");
}
```

and the message is shown. Do you have any idea why this function in not called?

Thanks!

EDIT: I compile JSON framework as a static lib. The call is made in the same lib.
When I compile it as exe it runs without any problem.

Comment: is your framework added and copied in compile time? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972904/adding-a-framework-to-xcode-4

Comment: @Marek Sebera I compile JSON framework as a static lib. The call us made in the same lib.

Comment: try look up definition of NSString extending code, and check everything is just fine.

Comment: @Marek Sebera Is weird that when I compile same code as executable instead of static library it's working without any problem.

Comment: try to check steps to configure static library use in this article: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/

Comment: The code is added in a bigger static library that works without any problem. I use bjam to build the project, so the standard configuration steps can't helm me. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You need to both link your static library and your final executable with the `-ObjC` linker option.

The `-JSONValue` method is implemented as a *category* on the `NSString` class in the file `NSString+SBJSON.m` file.  Because of how the dynamic runtime works in Objective-C, categories defined in static libraries don't get loaded up unless you link with the `-Objc` flag.  If the category doesn't get loaded, then dynamic binding fails, and you get the dreaded "doesn't respond to selector" exception.

Comment: You might have to use the `-all_load` flag too.